# How to reassign and increase the value of string variable

Tags: java, c++

I have the next example in C++:

```
this->name=new char[strlen(nom)+1];
```

So, I want to know how can I implement this example in java. The class have a :

```
private String name;
```

and I want to implement this method:

```
public void setNombre(String nom)
```

I try to do:

```
this.name= new String(nom.length()+1);
```

In  C++:

```
this->name=new char[strlen(nom)+1];
```

I try to do:

```
this.name= new String(nom.length()+1);
```

Comment: Do you understand what the C++ code does?

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable in java. In your C++ version it looks like you are creating an empty array of chars with the size of `nom` + 1.
You cannot assign an empty array of chars to a String in Java. Well, you can create a String full of `'\u0000'`, but then you will never be able to modify your String after that, so I really don't see the purpose.

EDIT : I think that you just want to set the name to the value `nom` so you can do:

```
public void setNombre(String nom){
  this.name = nom;
}
```

But that's not what your C++ code does.